# Prove that $a^b\cdot b^c \cdot c^a \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have to prove that

$a^b\cdot b^c\cdot c^a \leq 1$ given that $a+b+c=3$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers

My approach:

By AM-GM,

$a^b\cdot b^c \cdot c^a \leq (\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3})^3$

Now I am not sure how to proceed and in the solution, it goes like this:

${ab+bc+ca\over 3}\leq {a+b+c\over 3}=1$

I dont get the above statement, am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You should state that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive real numbers in your question (the inequality is untrue for $(a,b,c)=(2,2,-1)$).  AM-GM should give you $a^bb^cc^a\leq \left(\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\right)^3$.  For the remaining part of the problem, use AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz to establish $ab+bc+ca\le \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$,

Comment: @h-squared $$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}-ab+bc+ca= \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca}3\geq0$$ by AM-GM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1=$\frac {(a+b+c)^2}{9}$=$\frac {a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca}{9} \ge \frac {ab+bc+ca+2ab+2bc+2ca}{9}$

$\Rightarrow 1 \ge \frac {3(ab+bc+ca)}{9}$

$\Rightarrow 1 \ge \frac {(ab+bc+ca)}{3}$

We have used standard inequality that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ $\ge$ ab+bc+ca

Answer (score -1):

By Jensen for the concave function $\ln$ and by the Batominovski's reasoning we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}a^b=e^{\sum\limits_{cyc}b\ln{a}}=e^{3\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{b}{3}\ln{a}}\leq e^{3\ln\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{3}\cdot a\right)\right)}=e^{3\ln\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}}\leq e^{3\ln\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2}=1.$$